# Double meaning for "Family matters"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

There are [several shows or books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Matters_(disambiguation)) called "Family matters". To me, there's a double meaning. "Matters" is either a noun, meaning "something regarding the family", or it's a verb, something like "family is important".

Is this intended ? Do you, as native speakers, understand one of the meanings more than the other ?

Comment: Whether the expression *Family matters* is intended to be ambiguous, depends entirely on the context and the speaker. However,  the word *matters" is often used in such ambiguous fashion. One example is the BBC radio programme entitled *Business Matters*.

Comment: @RonaldSole I'm asking for when it's the title of something, there's often no context.

Comment: As you say, there is more than one definition for "matters", but you can't know which one it is without any context. I think both that you mention are popular.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Without the context, there's no way of knowing. It's like asking whether the words *sanction an action* mean permitting it or penalising it. Only context makes the meaning clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, likely it was intended.

Family is important.

Things that matter to the family. This could also often infer that it is not business to be shared outsiders. (Father's Last Will and Testament is a family matter and not to be discussed with the non-family member.)